# ContourPlot of implicit function doesn't work when I square the equation

Tags: plotting

When I try this

```
ContourPlot[e (-208 Sqrt[1 - e^2] - 205 Sqrt[4 - e^2] + 
    2 e^2 (Sqrt[1 - e^2] + Sqrt[4 - e^2])) + 400 Sin[\[Phi]]== 0, {\[Phi],
   0, 2*\[Pi]}, {e, -1, 1}]
```

It works and give nice plot but when I square the equation

```
ContourPlot[(e (-208 Sqrt[1 - e^2] - 205 Sqrt[4 - e^2] + 
    2 e^2 (Sqrt[1 - e^2] + Sqrt[4 - e^2])) + 400 Sin[\[Phi]])^2== 0, {\[Phi],
   0, 2*\[Pi]}, {e, -1, 1}]
```

Nothing comes out; same thing happens if I take `Abs[]`. I don't understand why these two are not equivalent to each other.  Since usually I deal with complex equations, I need let the norm equal to zero, thus either square or Abs comes out. Is there a way to let the latter one works? Thanks

Comment: If you're lucky you can do it symbolically too, with `f` being your function: `sols = Solve[f[\[Phi], e]^2 == 0, {e}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{\[Phi], e} /. sols], {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}]`